# How to calculate bounding box area?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have got the output of bounding box using `regionprops`.

For an image I got the output for `regionprops('BoundingBox')` as below:

> 52.5000 70.5000 287 165

Are these 4 coordiantes like leftmost x-coord and y-co-ordinate?

How to calculate bounding box area using the above output.

Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first two are the left most x and y coordinates respectively. The next two values are the lengths in the x and y direction respectively (starting from the x and y coordinates). So for area you need to multiply the last two values (e.g., 287*165). For more information see the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/regionprops.html#bqkf8hf) for `regionprops('BoundingBox')`.